# How to make search match similar words in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Im building a auto-suggest which will suggest similar words like "cat" when searching for "kat". How to match similar words in elasticsearch,so that I can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I feel [phonetic analyzer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-phonetic) is a good choice here. It tries to map words with similar sounds ( while pronouncing ) into a single token. In your example kat and cat would be the same for this analyzer.